# TableView inside UIViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, xcode4.2

I'm want to put a tableView inside a UIViewController, because I need a toolbar in the top of the view and i therefor can't use the tableViewController. I have created a tableView class and put the what i thought would be the needed functions inside it, but i must be missing something, or have put something wrong somewhere.

.h

```
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface TestTV : UITableView
@property(strong,nonatomic)NSArray *arr;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "TestTV.h"

@implementation TestTV
@synthesize arr = _arr;

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    _arr = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"HEJ",@"FOO", nil];
    return _arr.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    NSString *cellValue = [_arr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

    return cell;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably don't want to subclass `UITableView`. Instead, in your view controller subclass, declare your intention to implement the appropriate delegate and data source protocol:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Then, in the implementation file of your view controller, implement the methods you've defined above.

Finally, in Interface Builder (or programmatically) set both the `delegate` and `dataSource` outlets of the table view to be equal to its superview's view controller (in IB, this view controller is File's Owner).

You can make the data array a property of the view controller as well.

Comment: Now i can't segue from the cells in the tableView or from any buttons in my toolbar

Comment: If you're talking about Storyboard segues, I'm not familiar with them. On the other hand, surely you can use `IBAction`s and the `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method to achieve whatever you want.

Comment: Any chance of getting an updated version of this answer?  I'm trying it, but getting an error statin that you cannot specialize the non-generic type UIViewController...